# comparing gene expression distributions with replicates

Tags: distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have gene expression data for single cells (hundreds per sample) in two conditions that I would like to compare. For each condition I have 4 replicates. So in essence I need to compare 4 distributions versus 4 distributions.

I can calculate differential expression using 'pseudobulk' with DESeq2 or simply compare medians/means between these distributions, but if feels like I'm loosing a lot of information by disregarding the distribution.

Is there something like K-S test for situations when you have replicates of distributions?

Comment: Are these data on expression of a single gene, so you're interested in how the distribution of its expression among cells differs among the 2 conditions? Or is this single-cell RNAseq data, with potentially thousands of genes? If the latter, do you want to compare distributions of all those genes among the cells between the 2 conditions? Just what do you wish to compare? Please be more specific about the "distributions" you want to compare, and add that information to the question rather than responding in a comment, as information in comments can be hard to find, or even can be lost.